# android Kochava SDK integration crashes the app with google sdk

Tags: android

I just integrated Kochava SDK to my app recently. While I installing or running apk first time its crashed, but its working fine while running second time! However I also checked by generating signed(released) apk and then installing manually on device then its continuously crashing!

Here is my Project `gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        maven {url "http://kochava.bintray.com/maven"}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
        jcenter()
        google()

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven"
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {url "http://kochava.bintray.com/maven"}
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And Module `gradle` file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xyz.xyz.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 31
        versionName "4.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    aaptOptions {
        ignoreAssetsPattern "!*ffprobe"
        ignoreAssetsPattern "!*ffmpeg"
        ignoreAssetsPattern "!arm"
        ignoreAssetsPattern "!x86"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

android.buildTypes.each { type ->
    type.buildConfigField 'String', 'Base_URL', WEBServiceBaseURL
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //Android necessary...
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    //Support libs...
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    //Facebook ads
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:5.6.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.6.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.41.0'
    //Firebase
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.6.4'
    //FFMPEG
    implementation 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'
    //Image crop
    implementation 'com.naver.android.helloyako:imagecropview:1.2.2'
    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    //Exo Player
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.5'
    //Progress bar
    implementation 'com.dinuscxj:circleprogressbar:1.3.0'
    //Range seekbar
    implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.3'
    //Glide...
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    //GPUImage...
    implementation 'jp.co.cyberagent.android:gpuimage:2.0.3'
    //Fetch a downloader library...
    implementation "androidx.tonyodev.fetch2:xfetch2:3.1.4"
    implementation "androidx.tonyodev.fetch2okhttp:xfetch2okhttp:3.1.4"
    //Downloader for Android 19...
    implementation 'com.mindorks.android:prdownloader:0.6.0'
    //Lottie...
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.2.0'
    //Volley for Anfroid 4!
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    //Introduction for any screen...
    implementation 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.0.0'
    //ViewPagerEffects...
    implementation 'com.eftimoff:android-viewpager-transformers:1.0.1@aar'
    //Kochava...
    implementation 'com.kochava.base:tracker:3.6.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.1'
    //AVLoader...
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation project(path: ':jiaozivideoplayer')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I also implemented `Application class` as per suggestion and rule:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MultiDex.install(this);

        final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
                .kits(new Crashlytics())
                .debuggable(true)
                .build();
        Fabric.with(fabric);

        AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);
        AudienceNetworkAds.isInAdsProcess(this);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.app_id));

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            PRDownloaderConfig config = PRDownloaderConfig.newBuilder()
                    .setReadTimeout(30_000)
                    .setConnectTimeout(30_000)
                    .build();
            PRDownloader.initialize(getApplicationContext(), config);
        }

        Tracker.configure(new Tracker.Configuration(getApplicationContext())
                .setAppGuid("koboo-8bod4gz3")
                .setLogLevel(Tracker.LOG_LEVEL_INFO)
        );
    }
}
```

Above code is OK for Kochava integration. But another thing is that, here I also need all those google and firebase sdk! So, may be its problem is in between google sdk and Kochava sdk! But I need can't remove google sdk or crashlytics and also I need to integrate Kochava for tracking my application in Ad campaign in "Tik Tok" as per its suggestion!

Well if I don't initialize `Tracker.configure(....);` in `application class` then app run fine and not crashing but then Kochava not working!

So, after initialize `Tracker.configure(...);` Kochava sdk it will be generate error:

```
2019-12-03 15:33:14.254 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: xyz.xyz.myapplication, PID: 6113
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/aidl/BaseStub;
    at com.android.installreferrer.api.InstallReferrerClientImpl.startConnection(InstallReferrerClientImpl.java:133)
    at com.kochava.base.c$a.run(Unknown Source:15)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.aidl.BaseStub" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/videostatusmaker.videostatus.boo-Ptd9gTEkM8rXlvGCnCByPg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/videostatusmaker.videostatus.boo-Ptd9gTEkM8rXlvGCnCByPg==/lib/x86, /data/app/videostatusmaker.videostatus.boo-Ptd9gTEkM8rXlvGCnCByPg==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.android.installreferrer.api.InstallReferrerClientImpl.startConnection(InstallReferrerClientImpl.java:133) 
    at com.kochava.base.c$a.run(Unknown Source:15) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

May be there is some problem in Kochava library or something I missing in integration?! Please tell me what is the problem? Or it is not suitable with google sdk?

[Here](https://support.kochava.com/sdk-integration/android-sdk-integration/) is the link for Android Kochava SDK integration.

Comment: You need to configure your Proguard rules to exclude these files.

Comment: What's your `buildTools` version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you have more than one module in your app then put all Kochava `dependencies` in all of those module :

```
implementation 'com.kochava.base:tracker:3.6.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
```

These all must be in all module level `gradle` files. This is not mentioned is in documentation but you can try it. Because I tried your code in my application and I also have Google ads and other Google's libraries and also have three modules in my app. But added these libraries in all modules than its work perfectly!

I don't know if you have more than one module in your app but if there is than this will helpful.

Comment: Well its work only for few days! Because Google forward the mail today "We recently announced that we’ll be deprecating the install_referrer intent broadcast mechanism." And they saying that switch to "Play Install Referrer Library". Sorry all about may not helpful now ):

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

It has been fixed by google, on the same version...

It should work now, if it's still crashing it's probably linked to the previous version being cached, the following should fix it:

`implementation('com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.1') { changing .= true}`

More information here: https://github.com/adjust/android_sdk/issues/402

---

Try with `com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0` instead of `1.1`

Looks like `IGetInstallReferrerService` expects `com.google.android.aidl.BaseStub` in the `1.1` implementation, which does not come with `installreferrer`

Comment: I tried `com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0` but not working yet. omitting same error!

Answer (score 0):

mVck is correct and as far as we can tell, it's likely on Google's end and looks to be specific to version 1.1 of their library. This is our theory because it appears others on SO are experiencing similar issues with other vendor SDKs.

We've reached out to our Google reps to confirm, but in the meantime, please 
stay on version 1.0 of Google's library as indicated above. Once we receive confirmation we'll be sure and update our support documentation. Thanks!

Comment: We have dead line of March 1 2020 by Google!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same thing and what fixed it for me was to delete the install referrer dependency from my `gradle` cache and then re-sync with `gradle`. I think it was something to do with the cached `aar`. It's bizarre though because it was fine earlier this week and the `aar` didn't change as far as I'm aware. Regardless, deleting it and re-syncing did the trick for me.

Comment: How can i do this? I removed both my ~/.gradle & .gradle in my project dir. Still getting an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble downgrading to 1.0 after attempting to fix this issue with the 1.1.1 fix. In my case the installreferrer was adding the permission `READ_PHONE_STATE` to my application. Gradle was attempting to resolve 1.1 even after I backed down the version to 1.0 in my app.gradle.

In order to fix this I now force installreferrer to use version 1.0.

```
dependencies {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
    }

    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
}
```

Comment: again I repeat! We have dead line of March 1 2020 by Google! They will remove `com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0` soon! against 1.1