# Android installreferrer1.1 bug

Tags: android, google-play-services

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library.html), there was no problem in version 1.0, and it crashed after upgrading to 1.1.

```
implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0' // no crash
implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.1' // crashed
```

This is my code:

```
private lateinit var referrerClient: InstallReferrerClient
private fun initReferrer() {
    referrerClient = InstallReferrerClient.newBuilder(this).build()
    referrerClient.startConnection(object : InstallReferrerStateListener {

        override fun onInstallReferrerSetupFinished(responseCode: Int) {

        }

        override fun onInstallReferrerServiceDisconnected() {
        }
    })
}
```

This is Crash info:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/aidl/BaseStub;
    at com.android.installreferrer.api.InstallReferrerClientImpl.startConnection(InstallReferrerClientImpl.java:133)
```

Answer (score 0):

Been hitting this error also and seems like it was on the library itself I am now downgrading it back to 1.0 because there is no update yet.

Another SO question that is related.
[android Kochava SDK integration crashes the app with google sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59154673/android-kochava-sdk-integration-crashes-the-app-with-google-sdk)

Comment: I back to 1.0 too

Answer (score 0):

FYI, 1.1.1 is out and the issue seems to be fixed, you can now get rid of the annoying warnings.